# How to convert infix expression with functions in expression to binary tree?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, infix-notation

Here is the example expression: (A + B * C^D - A + (-)B)/(sin(A) + pow(C, D) - ln((A + B )/ C))

I was thinking about converting this infix expression to postfix where functions sin, ln and pow have same priority as other operands like A,B,C...

Then I wanted to convert that postfix expression to tree using stack?

Is this good idea or is there something better I can do?

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-grammar-and-precedence-parser-in-toc/ for the "something better" that you can do.  The reason why it is better is that while a postfix expression is easy to convert to a tree, converting infix to postfix is exactly as hard as converting infix to a tree directly - the hard bit remains the same.

Comment: So which part of the problem are you having trouble with? My suggestion is that you start by creating a version than can work with multi-character variable names. Once you've done that, adding special handling of functions like `sin`, `ln`, and `pow`, is straightforward.